# Obtaining the probability of exceedance corresponding a given return period

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function, extreme-value

I have a time series of data (15 years). Following plots show the fitted PDF (generalized extreme value distribution) and corresponding CDF (i.e. 1 minus CDF).

The data used here is not the total data, but for a single month only. Sampling rate is 1 per hour, but some data is corrupt. Thus, I have less than 8766 datapoints per year.

My question is: How can I determine the value corresponding to a return period of $x$ years from the CDF?

Or: What is the probability of exceedance for a given return period?

[image: PDF]

[image: CDF]

**Edit:**
Is the following correct for my case?

$\text{Probability of exceedance} = ({\text{Return period} \cdot \frac{8766 \, \text{hours}/\text{year} }{12\, \text{month}/ \text{year}}})^{-1}$

Comment: What do you mean by "probability of exceedance", do you mean the probability that your random process $X_t$ will be greater than some critical value $\alpha$ at some point between time interval $T$? What is nature of your process are $X_1, \dots, X_t$ i.i.d from generalized extreme value distribution?

Comment: What I mean is $P(X > a)$ with $a$ being the value corresponding to the return period I am looking for